# Adding rows together to populate new field in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

How do I add the values in columns 11_acciden, 12_acciden, 13_acciden, and 14_acciden in order to populate the total_acci column?

[image: attribute table question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Field Calculator, you are able to create an expression for the calculation of each row in a given field.  There are two languages that you can use to write the expression: VB and Python.  At the top of the calculator, you'll see where you can choose which language should be used to interpret the code you have entered.

If you select VB, you need to wrap the field names like so [fieldname], if you choose Python you have to wrap them this way !fieldname!.

I'm more used to using Python, so I'd recommend that you select Python up at the top, and then enter the following:

```
!11_acciden!+!12_acciden!+!13_acciden!+!14_acciden!
```

The numbers in your columns are aligned on the right, I'm assuming that the field type is some type of number (integers, double, etc.)  So it seems like it should work just fine.

Comment: glad to hear it! in that case could you click the checkmark to mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Field Calculator.  Right Click on Total_acci, select Field Calculator. You'll get an option to build a query. Add the other three fields together.

If those are not an option, you may need to change the data type using ArcCatalog.

Comment: Yes, Field Calculator, though it's not actually an SQL query that you are able to build, it's either a bit of VB code or a bit of Python code, depending on the parser you choose.  If you select Python you should be able to paste this code into the expression box to get what you're looking for: `!11_acciden!+!12_acciden!+!13_acciden!+!14_acciden!`

Comment: the option to build a SQL query doesn't come up. When I try to add the fields in the calculator it says "there was a failure during processing, check the geoprocessing results window for results"

Comment: If you go to Geoprocessing-->Results, does the error give you any additional information?   Also, try the above, but instead of the !'s wrap the fields in brackets [].

Comment: im still getting the same error

Comment: What information is the Results window giving you?  If you could add some screen shots so we can see what your syntax looks like as well as what the error is, it would be helpful.

Comment: Are all of your data types matching in the fields you are trying to sum? If any of them are strings, rather than numerical values, you won't be able to add them until you convert to numerical values. First, add a numerical field and populate it by field calculating from the field that is currently stored as a string. Do this for any field you are trying to sum and repeat the field calculation above.